# Is there a way to find out which actions are calling a specific action in UFT (QTP)?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

We have reusable actions in UFT that are being called by other actions. Of course if I go inside a caller action, I can tell which actions it's calling.

But, for some reason, I need to know the opposite. I have a reusable action and I need to get a list of all other actions that are calling it. So, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**UFT does provide a way to check it, only caveat is it supports only if your tests are stored in ALM.**

To get the list of Actions which are using your reusable Action:

1. Open your test with reusable action.
2. Open **TestFlow view** if not open.
3. Right-click on your reusable Action and select **Action Properties**.
4. Go to **Used By** tab.

Here you'll get the list of all the test along with actions which are calling that reusable action.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but our actions are not stored in ALM

Comment: Then you won't be able to able to get that list without creating a temp file in which you'll write Action/test name from which you are calling your reusable action and you'll keep on adding the entries in it.